# If $\cos x = -15/17$ with $x$ in quadrant III, find the exact value of $\sin 2x $ and the quadrant of $2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\cos x = -15/17$ with $x$ in quadrant III, find the exact value of $\sin 2x $ and the quadrant of $2x$.

I'm stuck on finding the quadrant of $2x$, so far I've done:
$$\sin 2x = 2 \sin x\cos x$$

$$(-\frac8{15})(-\frac{15}{17})= $$

$$= \frac{120}{255} \Rightarrow \frac{24}{51}$$

Comment: Where does $-18/15$ come from?

Comment: note that $$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$ for all real $x$

Comment: Sorry, not -18/15, -8/15.

Comment: Where does $-8/15$ come from?

Comment: I got -8/15 because sin = o/h.
8 is the opposite and h is 15. sin is - because its the 3rd quadrant. Am I wrong? I have a tough time at math.

Comment: @Bill Look at Dr Graubner's equation. Do your proposed values of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ satisfy it?

Comment: ... $\sin x = -8/17,$ not $-8/15$

Comment: ah you are right. thanks for pointing that out, so the answer should be 2x = 240/289 and 2x = 56.14 degrees?

Comment: thank you to everyone who helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that $-\frac{15}{17}\approx -1$ thus $x\approx \pi$ and $2x \approx 0$ in the first quadrant.

To find $\sin 2x$ let use

- $\sin 2x=2 \sin x \cos x >0$
- $\sin x =-\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}$

Comment: Thank you again gimusi.

Comment: $x$ is not $\approx \pi$. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito I've used to express that it is near to $pi$, which symbol do you suggest to use?

Comment: I understand now what you wanted to say (for me a difference of $28^{\circ}$ is not for take the symbol  $\approx$). Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Without sign one has $$\cos x=\dfrac{15}{17}\iff\sin x=\frac {8}{17}$$
then $$\sin 2x=2\cdot\dfrac{15}{17}\cdot\frac {8}{17}=0.830449827$$
Now with signs one has, with $x$ in quadrant III,
$$\arccos\frac {15}{17}=28.07248694^{\circ}\Rightarrow x=180^{\circ}+28.07248694^{\circ}=208.07248694^{\circ}$$
Therefore $$2(208.07248694^{\circ})=416.1449738^{\circ}$$
Since $$416.1449738^{\circ}-360^{\circ}=56.1449738^{\circ}$$ the quadrant of $2x$ is the first one.